# How to add a CSS class to this php code

Tags: php, css

How can I add a CSS class to "هر متر طول" in this php code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'themefars_text_after_price' );

function themefars_text_after_price($price){

global $post;

$product_id = $post->ID;

$product_array = array( 1204,1202 );//add in the product IDs to add text after price

if ( in_array( $product_id, $product_array )) {

$text_to_add_after_price = ' هر متر طول '; //change text in bracket to your preferred text 

return $price . $text_to_add_after_price;

}else{

return $price; 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where this html tags are allowed where this text is going, but maybe something like this:

```
$text_to_add_after_price = '<span class="myclass"> هر متر طول </span>';
```

Change myclass to the class you want to use.